# predicting and calculating reliability test statistics from repeated multiple regression model in r

Tags: r, validation, lm

I want to run MLR on my data using lm function in R. However, I am using data splitting cross validation method to access the reliability of the model. I intend using "sample" function to randomly split the data into the calibration and validation datasets by 80:20 ratio. This I want to repeat in say 100 times. Without setting a seed I believe the model from the different samplings will differ. I came across the function in previous post here and it solves the first part;

```
lst <- lapply(1:100, function(repetition) {
mod <- lm(...)   
# Replace this with the code you need to train your model
return(mod)
})
save(lst, file="myfile.RData")
```

The concern now is how do I validate each of these 100 models and obtain reliability test statistics like RSME, ME, Rsquare for each of the models and hopefully obtain the confidence interval.

If I can get an output in the form of dataframe containing the predicted values for all the 100 models then I should proceed from there.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Average fitted values and obtain RMSE for regression. Take majority vote (if T, T, F, then T) and obtain mean misclassification rate if classification. | What is ME? | R squared would be no longer relevant - which is the correct R squared value? R squared is just a measure of fit of a single regression line and you've got 100 and not a single one will be your final measure of fit.| If you've got 100 coefficients sets, you can obtain confidence intervals for them empirically.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly recap your question: it seems that you want to fit an MLR model to a large training set and then use this model to make predictions on the remaining validation set. You want to repeat this process 100 times and afterwards you want to be able to analyze the characteristics and predictions of the individual models.

To accomplisch this you could just store temporary modelinformation in a datastructure during the modelgeneration and prediction process. You can then re-obtain and process all the information afterwards. You did not provide your own dataset in the description, so I will use one of R's built in datasets in order to demonstrate how this might work:

```
> library(car)
> Prestige <- Prestige[,c("prestige","education","income","women")]
> Prestige[,c("income")] <- log2(Prestige[,c("income")])
> head(Prestige,n=5)
                    prestige education      income women
gov.administrators      68.8     13.11 -0.09620212 11.16
general.managers        69.1     12.26 -0.04955335  4.02
accountants             63.4     12.77 -0.11643822 15.70
purchasing.officers     56.8     11.42 -0.11972061  9.11
chemists                73.5     14.62 -0.12368966 11.68
```

We start by initializing some variables first. Let's say you want to create 100 models and use 80% of your data for training purposes:

```
nrIterations=100
totalSize <- nrow(Prestige)
trainingSize <- floor(0.80*totalSize)
```

We also want to create the datastructure that will be used to hold the intermediate modelinformation. R is quite a generic high level language in this regard, so we will just create a list of lists. This means that every listentry can by itself again hold another list of information. This gives us the flexibility to add whatever we need:

```
trainTestTuple <- list(mode="list",length=nrIterations)
```

We are now ready to create our models and predictions. During every loopiteration a different random trainingsubset is created while using the remaining data for testing purposes. Next, we fit our model to the trainingdata and we then use this obtained model to make predictions on the testdata. Note that we explicitly use the independent variables in order to predict the dependent variable:

```
for(i in 1:nrIterations)
{
  trainIndices <- sample(seq_len(totalSize),size = trainingSize)
  trainSet <- Prestige[trainIndices,]
  testSet <- Prestige[-trainIndices,]

  trainingFit <- lm(prestige ~ education + income + women, data=trainSet)

  # Perform predictions on the testdata
  testingForecast <- predict(trainingFit,newdata=data.frame(education=testSet$education,income=testSet$income,women=testSet$women),interval="confidence",level=0.95)
  # Do whatever else you want to do (compare with actual values, calculate other stuff/metrics ...)
  # ...

  # add your training and testData to a tuple and add it to a list
  tuple <- list(trainingFit,testingForecast) # Add whatever else you need ..
  trainTestTuple[[i]] <- tuple # Add this list to the "list of lists"
}
```

Now, the relevant part: At the end of the iteration we put both the fitted model and the out of sample prediction results in a list. This list contains all the intermediate information that we want to save for the current iteration. We finish by putting this list in our list of lists.

Now that we are done with the modeling, we still have access to all the information we need and we can process and analyze it any way we want. We will take a look at the modeling and prediction results of model 50. First, we extract both the model and the prediction results from the list of lists:

```
> tuple_50 <- trainTestTuple[[50]]
> trainingFit_50 <- tuple_50[[1]]
> testingForecast_50 <- tuple_50[[2]]
```

We take a look at the model summary:

```
> summary(trainingFit_50)

Call:
lm(formula = prestige ~ education + log2(income) + women, data = trainSet)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-15.9552  -4.6461   0.5016   4.3196  18.4882 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -287.96143   70.39697  -4.091 0.000105 ***
education       4.23426    0.43418   9.752  4.3e-15 ***
log2(income)  155.16246   38.94176   3.984 0.000152 ***
women           0.02506    0.03942   0.636 0.526875    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.308 on 77 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8072,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7997 
F-statistic: 107.5 on 3 and 77 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

We then explicitly obtain the model R-squared and RMSE:

```
> summary(trainingFit_50)$r.squared
[1] 0.8072008
> summary(trainingFit_50)$sigma
[1] 7.308057
```

We take a look at the out of sample forecasts:

```
> testingForecast_50
        fit       lwr      upr
1  67.38159 63.848326 70.91485
2  74.10724 70.075823 78.13865
3  64.15322 61.284077 67.02236
4  79.61595 75.513602 83.71830
5  63.88237 60.078095 67.68664
6  71.76869 68.388457 75.14893
7  60.99983 57.052282 64.94738
8  82.84507 78.145035 87.54510
9  72.25896 68.874070 75.64384
10 49.19994 45.033546 53.36633
11 48.00888 46.134464 49.88329
12 20.14195  8.196699 32.08720
13 33.76505 27.439318 40.09079
14 24.31853 18.058742 30.57832
15 40.79585 38.329835 43.26187
16 40.35038 37.970858 42.72990
17 38.38186 35.818814 40.94491
18 40.09030 37.739428 42.44117
19 35.81084 33.139461 38.48223
20 43.43717 40.799715 46.07463
21 29.73700 26.317428 33.15657
```

And finally, we obtain some more detailed results about the 2nd forecasted value and the corresponding confidence intervals:

```
> testingPredicted_2ndprediction <- testingForecast_50[2,1]
> testingLowerConfidence_2ndprediction <- testingForecast_50[2,2]
> testingUpperConfidence_2ndprediction <- testingForecast_50[2,3]
```

**EDIT**
After rereading, it occured to me that you are obviously not splitting up the the same exact dataset each time. You are using completely different partitions of data during each iteration and they should be split up in a 80/20 fashion. However, the same solution can still be applied with minor modifications.

Also: For cross validation purposes you should probably take a look at `cv.lm()`

Description from the R help:
This function gives internal and cross-validation measures of predictive accuracy for multiple linear regression. (For binary logistic regression, use the CVbinary function.) The data are randomly assigned to a number of ‘folds’. Each fold is removed, in turn, while the remaining data is used to re-fit the regression model and to predict at the deleted observations.

**EDIT: Reply to comment**.
You can just take the means of the relevant performance metrics that you saved. For example, you can use an `sapply` on the `trainTestTuple` in order to extract the relevant elements from each sublist. `sapply` will return these elements as a vector from which you can calculate the `mean`. This should work:

```
mean_ME <- mean(sapply(trainTestTuple,"[[",2))
mean_MAD <- mean(sapply(trainTestTuple,"[[",3))
mean_MSE <- mean(sapply(trainTestTuple,"[[",4))
mean_RMSE <- mean(sapply(trainTestTuple,"[[",5))
mean_adjRsq <- mean(sapply(trainTestTuple,"[[",6))
```

Another small edit: The calculation of your MAD looks rather strange. It might be a good thing to double check if this is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you Jellen Vermeir for the wonderful response. Below is my data https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1rul8cbxvygvr6/data.csv?dl=0 outcome variable is Bud. I included the following lines for the need tests:
valResiduals <- testSet[,1]- valPredict   # validation residuals
ME<-mean(valResiduals)
MAD<-mean(abs(valResiduals))
MSE <- mean(valResiduals^2)
RMSE <- sqrt(MSE)    # validation RMSE
adjRsq<- 1 - sum((testSet[,1]-valPredict)^2)/sum((testSet[,1]-mean(testSet[,1]))^2)
tuple <- list(valPredict,ME,MAD,MSE,RMSE,adjRsq) # 
trainTestTuple[[i]] <- tuple # } 
How do I find the averages of the 100 models

Comment: I replied to your comment at the bottom of my answer for readability purposes.